# Pick's theorem and the gamma function?

Tags: gamma-function, plane-geometry, digamma-function

Pick's theorem concerns "simple" polygons with vertices in $\mathbb Z^2.$ "Simple" means they have neither self-intersections nor holes. It says
$$
A = I + \frac B 2 -1
$$
where $A$ is the area of the polygon, $I$ is the number of points in $\mathbb Z^2$ in the interior, and $B$ is the number of points in $\mathbb Z^2$ on the boundary.

Area is an **additive** set function: If you chop a polygon into two polygons then its area is the sum of their areas.

In order to make this function **additive**, we had to subtract $1.$

The gamma function is
$$
\Gamma(\alpha) = \int _0^\infty x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x} \, dx,
$$
so the measure $f_\alpha(x)\, dx = \dfrac{x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \, dx$ for $x>0$ is a probability measure.

This convolution identity holds:
$$
(f_\alpha*f_\beta)(x) = \int_0^x f_\alpha(u) f_\beta(x-u)\, du = f_{\alpha+\beta}(x).
$$
In order to make the index in this convolution equal to the **sum** of the two separate indices, we had to subtract $1$ from $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the exponent.

Are these two instances of subtraction of $1$ being just the thing needed in order to achieve additivity both instances of some common general proposition?

Comment: I don't think so. The $1$ in Pick's theorem is some kind of Euler characteristic business, whereas the $1$ in the gamma function integral can be understood by writing it as $\int_0^{\infty} x^{\alpha} e^{-x} \frac{dx}{x}$, noting that $\frac{dx}{x}$ is Haar measure on the multiplicative group of the positive reals.